# How to put a table in background through an UIViewController?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a table within an UIView. All of this content is created in an UIViewController. For example, I have labels buttons etc in this UIView and the problem is, when I select a line I wanted to this UIView be in the background. The problem is when I use the `override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)` only the table stays in background, and it makes sense because the override is all about the table. How can I make this possible? I can't think of another solution.
I'm using `xamarin native language and I don't use storyboard neither forms`

Comment: What do you mean by `put a table in background`?

Comment: I want to present a new view but I want the full UIView with the table in the background. But since I'm making that change in the rowselected , the "table part" is the only one that stays in the background

Comment: Ok, you should set the Full UIView as the superView of the new View instead of 
add the new View to tableView. If you can share some relevant code, I can explain clearer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a simple example for you. I add two `labels` and one `tableview` to the backView`enter code here`. Then present a new View in the `RowSelected` method.

As I mentioned in the comment, you should `add the presentView to the backView instead of tablview`. When creating the `tableVieSoure`, you can pass the `BackView` and then use it in the `RowSelected`: `middleTable.Source = new TableSource(tableItems,backView);`

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        UIView backView = new UIView();
        backView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
        backView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,0,300,500);
        View.Add(backView);

        UILabel topLabel = new UILabel(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,10,200,50));
        topLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        topLabel.Text = "I am top label";
        backView.Add(topLabel);

        UITableView middleTable = new UITableView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 60, 200, 300)); 
        string[] tableItems = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
        //you can pass the backView when create the tableView
        middleTable.Source = new TableSource(tableItems,backView);
        backView.Add(middleTable);

        UILabel bottomLabel = new UILabel(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 360, 200, 50));
        bottomLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.SystemPinkColor;
        bottomLabel.Text = "I am bottom Label";
        backView.Add(bottomLabel);
    }

}

public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{

    UIView mybackView;

    string[] TableItems;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource(string[] items, UIView backView)
    {
        TableItems = items;
        mybackView = backView;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return TableItems.Length;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

        //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        UIView presentView = new UIView();

        presentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

        presentView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(40,80,250,200);

        //add the presentView to the backView instead of tablview
        mybackView.Add(presentView);
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Feel free to ask me if you have any questions.